# UILocalNotification in iOS 9 and UNMutableNotificationContent in iOS 10?

Tags: iphone, swift3, ios9, ios10, uilocalnotification

I need to give backward compatibility (iOS 9) to a project. I came up with this:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

What should I write in Fallback? Do I need to create a local notification instance?

Comment: Yes, we need to write fallback logic for iOS 9 as APIs are not supported prior to the version of the OS in which they were introduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a small example on supporting both version:

Objective-c version:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    objNotificationContent.body = @"Notifications";
    objNotificationContent.badge = @([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1);
    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:60 repeats:NO];
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"identifier" content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
        }
        else {
        }
    }];
}
else
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeIntervalInterval:60];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Notifications";
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

Swift version:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "awesomeNotification"
    content.title = "Notification"
    content.body = "Body"
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "FiveSecond", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request) { (error) in
    }
}
else
{
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Notification"
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:60)
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications = [notification]
}
```

Comment: notification didn't fire in iOS 9 device, do we need to set the timezone too?

Answer (score 4):

Below iOS 10.0 for Local Notification write below code

```
     let notification = UILocalNotification()
     let dict:NSDictionary = ["key" : "value"]
     notification.userInfo = dict as! [String : String]
     notification.alertBody = "\(title)"
     notification.alertAction = "OK"
     notification.fireDate = dateToFire
     notification.repeatInterval = .Day
     notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: I did set the fire date though the notification didn't fire in iOS 9 device, do we need to set the timezone too? notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:1.0) as Date

Comment: No timezone setup not required. Cross check your firedate